# Reverting back to using prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs

I've installed https://github.com/lleger/Rails-3-jQuery and it worked fine, however, the rails helpers that I was using with prototype stopped working.

How can I get back to using prototype in order to use the rails helpers OR make the helpers work with jQuery (the last would be the ideal solution).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the gem you are using is not good enough. You should be using `jquery-rails`.
Install as follows

```
gem install jquery-rails
```

or add it to your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

and then do

```
rails g jquery:install
```

This not only removes the prototype.js, and downloads the jquery, but also (importantly!) downloads the adapted [rails.js](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js) that works with jquery and will make sure that all standard rails-helpers will keep on working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load jQuery *after* prototype, then call [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), for example:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Then use `$j` for jQuery instead of `$`.

Or, still calling [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), you can use `$` inside a function just for that, for example:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
//$ is prototype
(function($) {
  //$ is jQuery
})(jQuery);
//$ is prototype
```

Or say you're doing a `document.ready` handler, the short version would be:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
//$ is prototype
jQuery(function($) {
  //$ is jQuery, this runs when the DOM is ready
});
//$ is prototype
```

Answer (score 0):

The Rails 3 helpers should work with jQuery too. (Stuff like `link_to ..., :remote => true`), the only thing to do is to load jQuery and the new rails.js.

The exception is RJS related helpers I guess.

Nick Craver's tip will work to make jQuery and prototype work together.